# A non co-hopfian simple group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, hopfian

Is there a simple group (all normal subgroups are the group itself or the trivial group) that is non co-hopfian (there exists an injective group endomorphism that is not surjective) ?

Comment: I find it strange that you take the trouble to define a simple group but not a co-hopfian group, although I am sure many more people are already familiar with simple groups than with co-hopfian groups!

Comment: Edited to add a definition of a non-co-hopfian group ! Would be glad to re-word the question if necessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can find a finitary alternating group $G$ (which is necessarily simple) with a proper subgroup $H$ which is isomorphic to $G$.

I found this example by googling "co-hopfian simple" and using [this link](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Simple_not_implies_co-Hopfian) to a groupprops page which was nearly at the top.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if there are any finitely generated examples.

Comment: By the way, the simplicity of the infinite countable alternating group is a result of Onofri (1929).

Answer (score 1):

To answer Derek Holt's request: R. Thompson's group $V$ is a non-cohopfian finitely presented group. This is the group of right-continuous permutations of $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$ that are, outside a finite subset of $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]/\mathbf{Z}$, affine with slopes in $\{2^n:n\in\mathbf{Z}\}$. Then the pointwise stabilizer of $[1/2,1[$ is clearly isomorphic to $V$ (conjugating by $x\mapsto 2x$ yields an isomorphism). Furthermore, it is dis-cohopfian, in the sense that it has an injective endomorphism $f$ such that $\bigcap_{n\ge 0}\mathrm{Im}(f^n)=\{1\}$.

That $V$ is simple and finitely presented is classical (historically, it's the first such infinite example).